# GeoServer smooth isoline by style

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-styling

I need to get smooth isoline on geoserver by styles.
I tried to use answer from [GeoServer raster isoline style](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383505/geoserver-raster-isoline-style) but I get error with schema.
It looks like for LineSymbolizer there isn't possibility to apply interpolation.
How can I do it?